# Fitting ellipse to image data set

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scipy, data-fitting

I am working with a camera signal. The typical signal of the camera is simulated with:

```
import cairo
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = numpy.zeros((352, 352), dtype = numpy.uint8)
surface = cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data(
                        data, cairo.FORMAT_A8, 352, 352)

cr = cairo.Context(surface)
cr.scale(0.85, 1.15)
cr.arc(200, 150, 100, 0, 2. * numpy.pi)
cr.set_line_width(15)
cr.stroke()

plt.imshow(data, cmap = "gray", interpolation = "None")
plt.show()
```

[image: Simulated example data set]

From this image data set I need to obtain the following parameters: `x-center`, `y-center`, `radius`, `thickness`, `ellipticity`, `angle of the ellipse` of the white elliptical ring.

What would be a fast and accurate method to obtain these parameters?

A code snippet I obtained over the years is the following 2D Gaussian fit:

```
import scipy.odr

def gauss_2D(p, r):
  # p = [amplitude, x-cen, y-cen, x-waist, y-waist, angle_in_rad, z-offset]
  x = r[0,]
  y = r[1,]

  dx, dy = (x - p[1]), (y - p[2])

  xp = dx * numpy.cos(p[5]) + dy * numpy.sin(p[5])  
  yp = dy * numpy.cos(p[5]) - dx * numpy.sin(p[5])

  data = (p[0] * numpy.exp(-2 * (xp / p[3])**2 - 2 * (yp / p[4])**2)) 

  return data + p[6]

def fit_gauss(p_guess, data_set):
  rr = numpy.indices(data_set.shape[:2])
  N = rr.shape[1] * rr.shape[2]

  fix = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

  model = scipy.odr.Model(gauss_2D)
  data = scipy.odr.Data(rr.reshape((2, N)), data_set.reshape((1, N)))
  odr = scipy.odr.ODR(data, model, p_guess, ifixb = fix)
  odr.set_job(fit_type = 2)
  output = odr.run()

  coeff = output.beta
  coeff_sd = output.sd_beta

  return rr, coeff, coeff_sd
```

However, I have not been able to rewrite `gauss_2D` into a function that would work for an ellipse with a certain line thickness.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: What if you do a separate fit on the outer and inner edge? Like `findContours` and then render each contour as a thin (or perhaps even filled) polygon, do a fit on that. The calculate the thickness from that.